# Single sign-on using ADFS approach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, adfs3.0

One of my customers wanted to implement SSO using ADFS. I was thinking to do a POC for the same using ADFS in Azure. But one requirement is only some users have ADFS login and other user needs to use custom authentication using the identity provider.

Is it possible to use custom and ADFS authentication in the same web application? Like presenting a page with sign-in using SSO or sign-in with credentials?

My client just shared the federatedmetadata.xml. (Do we need to give the full URL DNS name + metadata URL when you create the new project?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use custom and ADFS authentication in the same web application? Like presenting a page with sign-in using SSO or sign-in with credentials?

If you're open to it, you could integrate your application with an identity provider, and that provider does this for you.

For example:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1205228/149166831-2dd3c622-404f-403c-b07d-b0b39a222dd0.png]

Your application [integrates with CAS as the IDP](https://fawnoos.com/2022/01/12/cas65-adfs/), and CAS presents this screen to the end user for the authn attempt. User can choose either option, and then once completed, they will be redirected back to your application to continue, and your application interacts with CAS to validate the user account/session. CAS itself is connected to your own account store, and is also integrated with ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "ADFS in Azure". The only way to do this is to run ADFS as a VM in Azure. Otherwise, you would use Azure AD.

Yes, you can federate ADFS with other identity providers so they both are accessible from the same login screen.

What other identity providers are you looking at?

ADFS is not a project, it's a server add-on and it's all done via configuration on the Windows server.

In terms of importing metadata, see [this](https://www.alemba.help/help/content/topics/sso%20technical%20reference%20guide/sso%20id%20provider%20import%20sp.htm).